# Not able to refer back to genes clustered in som analysis using R's kohonen package

Tags: r, som

I am stuck in a problem, I am trying to apply SOM analysis using the kohonen package in R. The dataset I am using is a gene expression dataframe. I am using the code given below,

```
dim(bink)
[1]  401 1198
```

Where bink is a dataframe having expression values for 1198 genes, where gene names are in the columns as shown below,

[image]

The rest of the code is given below,

```
grid <- somgrid(xdim = 5, ydim = 5, topo = "hexagonal")

som.wines <- som(scale(bink), grid = somgrid(xdim = 5, ydim = 5, "hexagonal"))
str(som.wines)
plot(som.wines, type = "mapping")
```

After applying the code above I get the plot shown below,

[image]

But I am not able to get the name of the genes clustered in each circle, I have tried to use the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863086/how-to-relate-back-to-original-data-points-in-a-self-organizing-map)  for which the code is given below,

```
x= attr(som.wines$data,"scaled:center")

y= attr(som.mines$data,"scaled:scale")

for (i in 1:ncol(som.wines$data)){
z[,i] = som.wines$data[,i][som.wines$unit.classif==1] * y[i]+x[i]
}
```

Then I am getting the error given below,

```
# Error in 1:ncol(som.wines$data) : argument of length 0
```

I also tried changing the way to access the data by using `som.wines$data[[1]]` but it does not work.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data(wines)` as an example.

`som.wines <- som(scale(wines), grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))`

Each big circle in your plot is a cluster of samples found in the data by rows.
The profiles of the clusters are stored in `som.wines$codes`. Each line here is a cluster, V1 - Vx. This corresponds, obviously, to the number of big circles. You find the associated rows, i.e. the original data, in `som.wines$unit.classif`.

Associate the clusters with your original data with

```
cbind(wines, cluster=som.wines$unit.classif)
```

The arrangement of big circles used in the plot correspond with numbers in `som.wines$codes` in that the bottom left big circle is `V1` and the top right is `Vx`, i.e. the last cluster.